# css select inside tag

Tags: html, css

i have this css:

```
.test1 {
font-size:10pt;
}

.test2 {
font-size:12pt;
}
```

and i have this html :

```
<div class='test1'>name</div>
<div class='test2'>desc_name</div>


<div class='test1'>family</div>
<div class='test2'>desc_family</div>


<div class='test1'>password</div>
<div class='test2'>desc_pass</div>
```

what i have to do is to select the class test1 but only the tags that contains "family" inside the tag and give a background

i need a solution with css only, i dont need to change inside the html

is it possible ?
Thank You

Comment: This isn't possible with CSS, there's no way to select an element based on its text, or any other, content.

Comment: Pure CSS can't help you with tag content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using anything below CSS3 -

```
div.test1:contains("family") {
  background: *;
}
```

The `:contains()` pseudo-class was deprecated in CSS3 - ergo i wouldn't recommend it, nor am I entirely positive any browser completely supports it..  This answer is entirely subjective.

**Edit**: apparently the `:contains()` psuedo class works in jQuery (tested in v 1.9).

You can use jQuery to change your styles. (this solution calls for a CSS only solution, but if this is available, use it!)

```
$("div.test1:contains('family')").css({ background: "whatever" });
```

Comment: Have you tested which browsers this works in? I recall the `:contains()` pseudo-selector not being cross-browser.

Comment: From what I recall - it was working on IE7-9, FF, and Chrome.  We wrote Selenium 1 tests with this pseudo-class which worked fine.

Comment: The problem really is, that it doesn't work on any (? at least not on most) modern browsers. It's not even something unofficially supported etc.

Comment: The only *authoritative* information I can find on this selector is here:  http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/

Comment: Btw. I don't find it nor in CSS1 nor in CSS2 specification?

Comment: for jQuery, see it working : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/opIzC about :contains selector it looks like t dropped : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors  an old draft(fr)  http://www.w3.org/Style/css3-selectors-updates/WD-css3-selectors-20010126.fr.html#content-selectors

Answer (score 3):

Impossible with pure CSS. You cannot select on elements content with CSS(3 and higher).

The only you can do is specifying some attribute like:

```
<div class='test1' data-value="family">family</div>
```

And then select it with CSS:

```
div.test1[data-value='family'] { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple class something like this,

```
.test1 {
font-size:10pt;
}
.test2 {
font-size:12pt;
}
.family {
/* style */
}
```

and HTML code,

```
<div class='test1 family'>family</div>
<div class='test2'>desc_family</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class='test1 family'>family</div>
    <div class='test2'>desc_family</div>
```

I would suggest this one in orther to prevent override

```
    .test1 {
    font-size:10pt;
    }
    .test2 {
    font-size:12pt;
    }
    .test1.family {
    /* style */
    }
```

Comment: also if ur content load dynamicly use JQUERY instead

Comment: but in my case, i only have access to CSS, so i cant add class to HTML